# Apache Ignite consumes more memory than expected

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, ignite, in-memory-database, off-heap

I deploy my ignite cluster on google kubenetes engine (gke), which consists of two ignite server nodes.

I have a table with 6,000,000 records, and each around 220 bytes, in total 1.33GB. I set one backups for this table and set 5 indexes. As the ignite mentioned capacity planning [here](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/administrators-guide/capacity-planning), these records will occupy 9.2G memory, and indeed in the graidgain control center I can see the total allocated memory is around 9.3G, but actually in gke console it shows about 18G.

I'm not sure what consumes this extra 9G memory resources.

Comment: Hi, Could you please provide a metrics dump from the logs (can be found by 'Metrics for local node'). I guess that total allocated memory is the size of memory region (offheap memory), but as you understand JVM requires some memory for heap, so eventually it can be around 18G.

Comment: yeah inded jvm heap takes some extra memory, thanks for your remind.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some updates:

I tuned some JVM parameters including heap size, GC, and metaspace. In particular, I set 512m for max heap size, use G1 GC, 200m metaspace size and 40% min free ratio, 80% max free ratio of metaspace.

Now the memory consumption is reduced to 11GB, which is acceptable.